# I can't retrieve new entry's label using bif:contains on Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I've just inserted a node on a DBPedia graph with this query:

```
INSERT DATA {
    GRAPH <http://dbpedia.org> {         
     <http://my.semantics/resources/California%20Assn.%20Of%20Realtors> a dbpedia-owl:Organisation;
                                                                        rdfs:label  'California Assn. Of Realtors'@en .
}}
```

And it works fine.
When I try:

```
SELECT ?label
WHERE {
<http://semantics.twist.systems/resources/California%20Assn.%20Of%20Realtors> rdfs:label ?label . }
```

The result is retrived: `California Assn. Of Realtors`.

However whenever I try something like:

```
select ?label
where
{<http://semantics.twist.systems/resources/California%20Assn.%20Of%20Realtors> rdfs:label ?label .
 ?label bif:contains 'California' .}
```

Nothing is returned.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of your bif:contains problem on virtuoso.
But you can use regex instead. Have a look here: https://coderwall.com/p/4v5b5w/sparql-free-text-search-instead-of-regex

I usually use FILTER + regex to solve problems like yours. And in the regex context, str(...) is commonly used.

Hope this will be of help.

Comment: As far as I understand I have to re-index Virtuoso full text search in order to make the query work, so I guess only ensuring the variable is a string does not make the trick

Comment: you're right my original answer is stupid, forget about it... please read the edited version